# Does Spring proxy request attributes?

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc, servlets

If somewhere I have a singleton `@Component` bean "Foo" with a `@Autowired` HttpSession or HttpServletRequest, does Foo *itself* have to be declared session (or request) scoped, or can I just keep it as a simple singleton --- in which case HttpSession and/or HttpServletRequest are probably already injected as scoped proxies anyway via Spring?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a pretty simple test to check behavior (Spring 4.0.0.RELEASE)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/service")
public class NewController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String test(ModelMap model) {
        System.out.println(requestEntity.request.getAttribute("type")); // get it
        requestEntity.request.setAttribute("type", "Scope"); // set it so that we can make sure that our second request doesn't contain it
        System.out.println(requestEntity.request.getClass());
        return "whatever";
    }

    @Autowired
    private Foo requestEntity;
}
```

and

```
@Component
public class Foo {
    @Autowired
    public HttpServletRequest request;
}
```

If you send a request, you'll note that the attribute returned is always `null` and that the class is something like

```
class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19
```

Therefore you are always getting a different `HttpServletRequest` object even though the `@Component` bean is singleton scoped.

---

Here's the explanation:

When you instantiate a `WebApplicationContent`, it registers some special `ObjectFactory` instances for resolving some *web* types in the underlying `BeanFactory`. This is done in `WebApplicationContextUtils.registerWebApplicationScopes(..)`. One of these is the following

```
beanFactory.registerResolvableDependency(ServletRequest.class, new RequestObjectFactory());
```

When Spring scans your beans and determines that it needs to autowire the `HttpServletRequest` (which is a sub type of `ServletRequest`) field, it will look in its map of resolvable dependencies and get this `RequestObjectFactory`.

Because this is an `ObjectFactory` and the injection target is an interface type, Spring will create a Proxy of that type that delegates to the object created/returned by the `RequestObjectFactory` on each request. This is done in `AutowireUtils.resolveAutowiringValue(..)`.

As such, your `Foo` bean does not need to be request scoped.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that Spring does use a proxy, yes.  Spring allows you to inject request or session-scoped objects into singleton-scope objects by injecting a proxy into the singleton.

For Spring MVC, I believe the injected proxy is backed by a `ThreadLocal` variable because each request is bound do a thread.  The real `HttpServletRequest` is then available via this injected proxy that delegates onto the `ThreadLocal` when invoked.

Therefore, you don't need to declare "Foo" to be session or request scoped and can keep it as a Singleton.